# Can someone spoof its IP address to mine when sending emails?

Tags: email, ip, ip-spoofing

Can someone spoof its IP address to mine when sending emails?
I know we can see the IP address of the sender in the email header. If someone had my IP, can he/she use it to show in email headers?
Even with handshake protocols?

I want to know if its possible to someone send emails while pretending to be me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely refer to the Received field in the mail header, i.e. something like this:

> ```
> Received: from e239-39.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com ([23.251.239.39]) by
>      mx-ha.gmx.net (mxgmx016 [212.227.15.9]) with ESMTPS 
>      ...
> ```

Each mail server on the path of the mail adds such a Received field on top of the mail header. The IP address in this line is determined by the mail server from the TCP connection. It can not be faked by the sender, since IP spoofing in a multi-exchange TCP connection (as  used in mail delivery) is not possible.

But, it is possible that the attacker simply adds their own Received fields into the mail before it gets delivered, which can contain any content defined by the attacker, including your IP address. These additional Received fields are usually simply passed through to the recipient. Since it is common that a mail contains multiple Received fields this can be used to confuse the target since it can be unclear which of these Received fields are actually added by a real mail server and which are faked.

Comment: And can they modify the headers to make it look like the email was sent by my IP address?

Comment: @MateusAlberghini: to cite myself: *"But, it is possible that the attacker simply adds their own Received fields into the mail before it gets delivered, which can contain any content defined by the attacker, __including your IP address__."*

Comment: Interesting. And is there a way to see if this happened? Are there any other fields used to identify the sender?

Comment: And the first IP address logged in the header corresponds to the first **server** this email reached or to the machine IP where the email **client** is running?

Comment: @MateusAlberghini: **Each** MTA adds its own Received field  **on top** of the others. But it is impossible to determine if any existing Received fields are added by previous MTA (i.e. real) or by the client itself (i.e. fake).

Comment: And when the receiver adds "Received fom x.x.x.x" this IP it gets from the incomming email's header of it takes from the SMTP request itself?

Comment: @MateusAlberghini: The IP address  shown as source in the Received field added by an MTA is the source IP of the TCP connection from the mail delivery, i.e. not taken from any mail header or from SMTP "request" (there is no such thing).

Comment: Ok, interesting. So if you take the first reliable server that logged "Received from" you can see the IP from the real origin of the email right?

Comment: @MateusAlberghini: Only as far as SMTP goes, i.e. in case of web based mails you get the address of the server, not of the client (browser).